# How to get yesterday and day before yesterday in linux?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I want to get sysdate -1 and sysdate -2 in variable and echo it. I am using below query which gives todays date as output.

```
#! /bin/bash
tm=$(date +%Y%d%m)
echo $tm
```

How to get yesterday and day before yesterdays date?

Comment: Do `date -d"yesterday"` and `date -d"yesterday -1 day"` work to you?

Comment: Please use YYYY-mm-dd  https://xkcd.com/1179/

Answer (score 77):

Here is another one way,

For yesterday,

```
date -d '-1 day' '+%Y%d%m'
```

For day before yesterday,

```
date -d '-2 day' '+%Y%d%m'
```

Comment: Note that the BSD `date` command (like macOS has) uses the `-v` switch for this. So `date -v '-1d' '+%Y%d%m'` would do what you want.

Comment: Sane version (iso 8601): `date -v '-1d' '+%Y-%m-%d'`

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 19):

1. Yesterday date

   ```
   YES_DAT=$(date --date=' 1 days ago' '+%Y%d%m')
   ```
2. Day before yesterdays date

   ```
   DAY_YES_DAT=$(date --date=' 2 days ago' '+%Y%d%m')
   ```

For any date you can use below one default it take 1 days. If its passing value that day before it take

```
ANY_YES_DAT=$(date --date=' $1 days ago' '+%Y%d%m')
```

Answer (score 7):

You can get the yesterday date by this:

```
date -d "yesterday 13:00 " '+%Y-%m-%d'
```

and day before yesterday by this:-

```
date -d "yesterday-1 13:00 " '+%Y-%m-%d'
```

Comment: `yesterday-1` and `yesterday -1` not working in RHEL 7.1, only `date -d "yesterday -1 day"`

Answer (score 5):

For older versions of BSD date (on old versions of macOS for example) which don't provide a `-v` option, you can get yesterdays date by subtracting 86400 seconds (seconds in a day) from the current epoch.

```
date -r $(( $(date '+%s') - 86400 ))
```

Obviously, you can subtract 2 * 86400 away for the day for yesterday etc.

**Edit:** Add reference to old macOS versions.