# Getting yesterday's date in Unix csh script

Tags: unix, csh, sunos

I currently have the below lines as part of my script:

```
#! /bin/csh

set thedate = `date "+%d_%m_%y"`
```

This sets thedate to today's date.

Does anyone know what I need to add to get the script to pick up yesterday's date instead?

I have tried

```
date -v "-1d"
date -d "-1 day"
```

but I get the errors

```
date: illegal option -- v
date: illegal option -- d
usage:  date [-u] mmddHHMM[[cc]yy][.SS]
    date [-u] [+format]
    date -a [-]sss[.fff]
```

I have then tried

```
set thedate = `date "+%d_%m_%y" --date="1 day ago"`
```

which when echoing thedate, still gives today's date.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get yesterday and day before yesterday in linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22043088/how-to-get-yesterday-and-day-before-yesterday-in-linux)

Comment: I get errors when I have tried what I have googled... for example, the message date: illegal option -- v ... or ... date: illegal option -- d @zappy

Comment: If that is the case then you should state that in the question. Otherwise people will just give you the same answer again. Put exactly what you tried into the question and give the errors in the question itself.

Comment: Please run `uname -s` in csh and tell us what it says. It should be your OS type.

Comment: The OS type is SunOS

Comment: OK. The `linux` tag you used was attracting answers for the GNU/Linux date command. Do you have a command named `gdate`? It should work the same as GNU/Linux `date`.

Comment: Updated question and given correct tags

Answer (score 2):

```sh
$(date "+%d_%m_%y" --date="1 day ago")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
date -d "-1 days" +"%a %d/%m/%Y"
```

The `-d "-1 days"` makes sure that the date of yesterday gets calculated.

The `+"%a %d/%m/%Y"` takes care of the output format (name, day, month, year).

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh

thedate=`date "+%d_%m_%y" --date="1 day ago"`

echo "${thedate}"
```

Working fine for me.
I dont know why you are using C-shell. I dont have C-Shell in my target. use shell(/bin/sh) or bash (/bin/bash)

Comment: Hello, It still prints today's date for some reason, C-Shell is used by the client, not my first choice

Comment: the date command I am running is:  set thedate = `date "+%d_%m_%y" --date="1 day ago"` and then echo $thedate which then outputs 07_01_20

Comment: just execute what exactly i posted in above answer , just change bin/sh to bin/csh and execute

Comment: the output is: thedate=07_01_20: Command not found
thedate: Undefined variable

Comment: Updated tags in your question. I have never tried this on SunOS and C-shell.